# ext4 partition ubuntu lost after Windows 7 installation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, ext4

I've got this problem:

I have one hdd and use ubuntu 12.10 on this hdd with several partitions(one nfts, two ext4 and one unallocated). today after windows 7 installation, and booting with live usb, i see that the ubuntu partition is gone. No ubuntu boot. testdisk says:

```
 P HPFS - NTFS             12 223 20  6361 253 36  101998592
 P HPFS - NTFS          15887   1  4 87965 254 59 1157949065 [XYZ]
 L Linux                87966   1  1 91200 254 59   51970208
```

so any idea how to recover the partition or the data from it?

Comment: Have you tried using a Ubuntu live cd/USB to see if Ubuntu recognizes the partitions ?
Windows overwrites the Ubuntu booloader, so if the partitions is still there, you will just have to reconfigure GRUB as documented here :
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Answer (score 0):

Installing Windows removed the Grub bootloader.

If you boot from a live USB and in a terminal type `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` where /dev/sda is your hard disk, you should get Grub back and Ubuntu too.

Comment: hey, thanks for reply. the thing is, the partition with ubuntu is gone, not the grub. grub you can fix with auto repair tool :boot-repair. but this doesnt help. so, the partition with installed ubuntu should be recovered. gparted shows that partition as : unallocated. so what to do?

Comment: PLs add the results of `sudo fdisk -l` to your question. If the partition is gone, then you might have to use the "recover partition" option in testdisk but **stop using the hard disk**. In any case, the windows install, will have caused a lot of data loss.

Comment: You can recover the partition if you **stop using the disk** right NOW. However as To Do mentioned it will likely have some data loss. You might be better just re-installing Linux. If you know the old partition sizies (which you do) you may be able to set your partition table back like it was and just keep going.